# Boost Spirit - Trimming spaces between last character and separator

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Boost Spirit newcomer here.

I have a string in the form of "Key:Value\r\nKey2:Value2\r\n" that I'm trying to parse. In that specific form, it's trivial to parse with Boost Spirit. However, in order to be more robust, I also need to handle cases such as this one:

"   My Key    : Value \r\n  My2ndKey  : Long<4 spaces>Value \r\n"

In this case, I need to trim leading and trailing spaces before and after the key/value separators so that I get the following map:

"My Key", "Value"

"My2ndKey", "Long<4 spaces>Value"

I played with qi::hold to achieve this but I get compile errors because of unsupported boost::multi_pass iterator with the embedded parser I was trying to use. There has to be a simple way to achieve this.

I read the following articles (and many others on the subject):

http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/parsing-a-list-of-key-value-pairs-using-spirit-qi/
http://boost-spirit.com/home/2010/02/24/parsing-skippers-and-skipping-parsers/

[Boost spirit parsing string with leading and trailing whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867600/boost-spirit-parsing-string-with-leading-and-trailing-whitespace)

I am looking for a solution to my problem, which doesn't seem to be entirely covered by those articles. I would also like to better understand how this is achieved. As a small bonus question, I keep seeing the '%=' operator, is this useful in my case? MyRule %= MyRule ... is used for recursive parsing?

The code below parses my strings properly except that it doesn't remove the spaces between the last non-space character and the separator. :( The skipper used is qi::blank_type (space without EOL).

Thanks!

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
struct KeyValueParser : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::map<std::string, std::string>(), Skipper> {
  KeyValueParser() : KeyValueParser::base_type(ItemRule) {
    ItemRule = PairRule >> *(qi::lit(END_OF_CMD) >> PairRule);
    PairRule = KeyRule >> PAIR_SEP >> ValueRule;
    KeyRule = +(qi::char_ - qi::lit(PAIR_SEP));
    ValueRule = +(qi::char_ - qi::lit(END_OF_CMD));
  }
  qi::rule<Iterator, std::map<std::string, std::string>(), Skipper> ItemRule;
  qi::rule<Iterator, std::pair<std::string, std::string>(), Skipper> PairRule;
  qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> KeyRule;
  qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> ValueRule;
};
```

Comment: If instead of what you did, you had provided something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b30f7a280f0d0e1), it'd be much easier to help you. I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, although I can't find it at the moment, [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7539f0ebf856e242) is a possible solution. Regarding your question about `%=`, you can see [here](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/nonterminal/rule.html#spirit.qi.reference.nonterminal.rule.expression_semantics) that it's basically the same as `=` except when there are semantic actions.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!
Can you post the solution as an Answer so I can mark it such?

The reason why I didn't post full code was because I was looking more for hints or explanation instead of a full blown solution like you kindly provided, but I'll be more explicit in the future. :)

Even though the solution works fine, I don't fully understand it. I noticed you introduced the skipper for both Key/Value rules, but I would've thought the qi::raw directive would also eat the leading/trailing spaces. Can you explain? Thanks

Also, thank you for the %= explanation link!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591694/how-to-extract-trimmed-text-using-boost-spirit) is the duplicate I was trying to find. Sadly it doesn't really explain how it works. I'll try to give an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `KeyRule = qi::raw[ +(qi::char_ - qi::lit(PAIR_SEP)) ];`

---

In order to see why, let's try to study several ways to parse the string `"a b :"`.

First let's keep in mind how the following parsers/directives work:

- [`lexeme[subject]`](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/lexeme.html): This directive matches `subject` while disabling the skipper.
- [`raw[subject]`](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/raw.html): Discards `subject`'s attribute and returns an iterator pair that points to the matched characters in the input stream.
- [`+subject`](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/plus.html): The plus parser tries to match 1 or more times its `subject`.
- [`a-b`](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/difference.html): The difference parser first tries to parse `b` and if `b` succeeds, `a-b` fails. When `b` fails, it matches `a`.
- `char_`: matches any char. It's a [`PrimitiveParser`](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parser_concepts/primitiveparser.html).
- `lit(':')`: matches `':'` but ignores its attribute. It's a [`PrimitiveParser`](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parser_concepts/primitiveparser.html).

---

1. **`lexeme[ +(char_ - lit(':')) ]`**: by removing the skipper from your rule you have an implicit lexeme. Since there is no skipper it goes like this:

> 'a' -> `':'` fails, `char_` matches 'a', the current synthesized attribute is "a"
>   ' ' -> `':'` fails, `char_` matches ' ', the current synthesized attribute is "a "
>   'b' -> `':'` fails, `char_` matches 'b', the current synthesized attribute is "a b"
>   ' ' -> `':'` fails, `char_` matches ' ', the current synthesized attribute is "a b "
>   ':' -> `':'` succeeds, the final synthesized attribute is "a b "

---

2. **`+(char_ - lit(':'))`**: Since it has a skipper every PrimitiveParser will pre-skip before being tried:

> 'a' -> `':'` fails, `char_` matches 'a', the current synthesized attribute is "a"
>   ' ' -> this is skipped before `':'` is tried
>   'b' -> `':'` fails, `char_` matches 'b', the current synthesized attribute is "ab"
>   ' ' -> this is skipped before `':'` is tried
>   ':' -> `':'` succeeds, the final synthesized attribute is "ab"

---

3. **`raw[ +(char_ - lit(':') ) ]`**: The subject is exactly the same as `2.`. The raw directive ignores `"ab"` and returns an iterator pair that goes from `'a'` to `'b'`. Since the attribute of your rule is `std::string`, a string is constructed from that iterator pair, resulting in `"a b"` which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I understood properly the other directives but I didn't know that qi::raw considers the skipper before returning the pair of iterators which effectively keeps the skipper in-between. :)